# SQL: select unique values where condition holds for all - can statement be improved?

Tags: sql

I've got a table like this:

```
i    j
------
A    2
A    3
A    7
B    8
B    7
C    2
D    9
```

I'd like to get all values of `i` that have no `j` values below 7, so here I'd want

```
result
-----
B
D
```

I've come up with:

```
select table.i 
from table
where table.i not in (
    select table.i from table where j < 7)
group by table.i
```

but it feels very clumsy. Can this be improved?

Comment: Why you won't use `SELECT i FROM tableName WHERE j > 7` ?

Comment: @iSR5 that would also give `A` here, which I don't want; I've clarified the question a bit--I want all `i` that have no `j` valueS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is fine, although I would use `not exists` rather than `not in`.

An alternative is `group by`:

```
select i
from t
group by i
having min(j) >= 7;
```

Or if your database supports `minus`/`except`:

```
select i
from t
except
select i
from t
where i < 7;
```

Comment: Thanks! Improves my confidence :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
select i
  from t 
  left join ( -- Get all i vlaues where j is < 7
              select distinct i 
                from t
               where j < 7
            ) x on t.i = x.i
 where x.i is null
```